# How to dynamically update labels captions in VBA form?

Tags: vba, excel, label

I want to dynamically set the caption for an array of labels (within a VBA form) based on values stored in a worksheet. Thus far I can set them one-by-one like this:

```
Label1.Caption = MySheet.Range("A1").Value
Label2.Caption = MySheet.Range("B1").Value
Label3.Caption = MySheet.Range("C1").Value ...
```

Having lots of labels that follow a recurrent pattern, I want to use something smarter, like:

```
'Method1
For i = 1 To X
    Dim MyLabel as Object: Set MyLabel = "Label" & i
    MyLabel.Caption = MySheet.Cells(i + 1, i).Value
Next i
'Method2
For i = 1 To X
    Label(i).Caption = MySheet.Cells(i + 1, i).Value
Next I
'Both Methods failed. I really appreciate some feedback on this.
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `Controls` object

```
For i = 1 To X
    Controls("Label" & i).Caption =  MySheet.Cells(i + 1, i).Value
Next
```

Comment: Would the same be possible if the labels are not inside a UserForm, but rather on a Worksheet?

Comment: What kind of controls are on the worksheet? Form controls or activex controls? You may want to post a new question so that it may not only help you but future visitors as well?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use this in VBA:

```
For i = 1 To X
    UserForm1.Controls("Label" & i).Caption =  MySheet.Cells(i + 1, i).Value
Next
```