# How to let a label = sum of other labels

Tags: excel, vba

I understand that labels are stored as text.

How can I convert my labels to numbers, so that I can have a label that's a sum of all other labels?

Comment: loop through all the labels. `Dim i As Long` `i = i + Int(Label)` (this if your numbers are integers).

Comment: @Damian one last question, I would like to make my label which is a caption to equal to a cell. How can I go about this?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20677557/7558682) this will help you.