# How to modify a Form.Control using a "Partially Qualified" name in a String?

Tags: excel, vba, controls

I have three subroutines that are essentially identical to the one below, hard coded with the `Partially Qualified Label Name`, i.e. `"Label's Name` without the `Index`.

```vb
Sub lblToggle2(ByRef lblYr As Long)
    Dim i
    Dim lblcnt As Long
    If Not lblYr = 0 Then
        lblcnt = wbCurYear - lblYr + 1
        Debug.Print lblYr, lblcnt
        For i = 1 To lblcnt
            Me.Controls("lblCostYrE" & i).Caption = lblYr
            Me.Controls("lblCostYrG" & i).Caption = lblYr
            lblYr = lblYr + 1
        Next i
    Else
        For i = 1 To 5
            Me.Controls("lblCostYrE" & i).Caption = vbNullString
            Me.Controls("lblCostYrG" & i).Caption = vbNullString
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

The sub above is based in part on [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20677557/18701211) and is called using:

```
Call lblToggle2(StartYear)
```

I am trying use one `Sub` to handle multiple `Label` combinations.

Here are two of several attempts.

Calling Code:

```
Call lblToggleTest1(StartYear, """lblCostYrG""", """lblCostYrE""")
Call lblToggleTest2(StartYear, """lblCostYrG""", """lblCostYrE""")
```

Subroutine Code:

```
Sub lblToggleTest1(ByRef lblYr As Long, lblG As String, lblE As String)
    Dim i
    Dim lblcnt As Long
 
    If Not lblYr = 0 Then
        lblcnt = wbCurYear - lblYr + 1
        For i = 1 To lblcnt
            Debug.Print lblYr, cntrl1.Name, cntrl2.Name, lblcnt
            Me.Controls(lblG).Caption = lblYr
            Me.Controls(lblE).Caption = lblYr
            lblYr = lblYr + 1
        Next i
    Else
        For i = 1 To 5
            Me.Controls(lblG).Caption = vbNullString
            Me.Controls(lblE).Caption = vbNullString
        Next i
    End If
End Sub

Sub lblToggleTest2(ByRef lblYr As Long, lblG As String, lblE As String)
    Dim i
    Dim lblcnt As Long
    Dim cntrl1 As Object
    Dim cntrl2 As Object
    cntrl1 = lblG & (i)
    cntrl2 = lblE & (i)
 
    If Not lblYr = 0 Then
        lblcnt = wbCurYear - lblYr + 1
        For i = 1 To lblcnt
        Debug.Print lblYr, cntrl1.Name, cntrl2.Name, lblcnt
            Me.Controls(cntrl1).Caption = lblYr
            Me.Controls(cntrl2).Caption = lblYr
            lblYr = lblYr + 1
        Next i
    Else
        For i = 1 To 5
            Me.Controls(cntrl1).Caption = vbNullString
            Me.Controls(cntrl2).Caption = vbNullString
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried declaring the `Label` variables as `Variant`, `Object`, and `String`.

I get `Object Not Found`, `Object Required`, or some other error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many quotes in your calling code.

Untested:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    lblToggleTest StartYear, "lblCostYrG", "lblCostYrE"
End Sub


Sub lblToggleTest(ByRef lblYr As Long, lblG As String, lblE As String)
    Dim i As Long, lblcnt As Long, haveYear As Boolean, v
    
    haveYear = lblYr <> 0 'was a start year provided?
    lblcnt = IIf(haveYear, wbCurYear - lblYr + 1, 5)
    
    For i = 1 To lblcnt
        v = IIf(haveYear, lblYr, vbNullString)
        Me.Controls(lblE & i).Caption = v
        Me.Controls(lblG & i).Caption = v
        If haveYear Then lblYr = lblYr + 1
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the response. That was the first iteration I attempted and it returned `could not find specified object`. I'm not sure what I did differently but it is now working as expected. Also, Thanks for the additional `Code Reduction` recommendation. Every time you provide an answer/suggestion my understanding improves dramatically. Marked as `Answered`.